# How can we plot ROC Curve for leave one out (LOO) cross validation using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc

On the scikit-learn website there is code for ROC curve for stratified kfold but no code is present for leave one out (LOO) cross validation. I tried by changing the code of kfold by loo but the result is nan. What can be the problem?

I checked scikit-learn website but no code is there for loo cross validation.

The code for stratified kfold is given in the link given below.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html

Comment: Please show us the code and unexpected result explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried to set n_splits to the number of data points in your dataset?

Comment: @Calimo Yes. I have tried this. Still the result is nun. No curve is displayed.

Comment: @Kumar please show us the code you used and unexpected result explicitly, as rvf asked already.

Comment: did you manage to find an answer for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756804/roc-curve-with-leave-one-out-cross-validation-in-sklearn